# Liquibase+k8s init container automation for new DDL and DML

Tags: kubernetes, liquibase

As Liquibase team has provided the solution of liquibase + k8s init container.
This would solve problem: in a cluster environment, apps may not able to start up because of the changeloglock.
The solution blog is this:https://www.liquibase.com/blog/using-liquibase-in-kubernetes.
But for production environment, how to make this solution in an automation process?
For example, for a java project using liquibase, we would add a NEW_DDL_001.xml under the resources folder, and update the db.changelog-main.xml.
Then we can merge the code to main branch and trigger jenkins to deploy. When Jenkins is running, it will scan the db.changelog-main.xml find that there is a new xml named: NEW_DDL_001.xml, it will lock the db, and run this ddl, after finishing, it will unlock the db.
These are all in automation process.
But with the liquibase + k8s init container solution, it says we have to manually run the command:

```
kubectl create configmap changelog-volume --from-file=NEW_DDL_001.xml
```

Using the NEW_DDL_001.xml to create configmap, then let the init container to read the configmap to run this ddl. This is a manually process. How to make it automatically?

Automation for deploying apps using liquibase + k8s init container.